# While loop not working in PHP

Tags: php

While loop not working not showing anything.

My code is working when I use without creating a function on the same page but when I create function on functions.php and call it, it does not work.

```
<?php 
include "include/db.php";

function search(){
    global $connection;
    $record_search = $_GET['search'];
    $record_search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $record_search);

    $query_search = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_name='$record_search' OR       u_roll='$record_search' ";
    $result_search = mysqli_query($connection, $query_search);
    if(!$result_search){
        die("FAIL" . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
    while ($row_search = mysqli_fetch_array($result_search)) {
        $name_search     =      $row_search[1];
        $f_search        =      $row_search[2];   
        $school_search   =      $row_search[3];
        $roll_search     =      $row_search[4];
        $email_search    =      $row_search[5];
        $class_search    =      $row_search[6];
    }
}
?>
```

and

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['search'])){
        global $connection;
        global $result_search;
        search();
        ?>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
   <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Father Name</th>
            <th>School</th>
            <th>Roll No</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Class</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td><?php echo @$name_search; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo @$f_search; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo @$school_search; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo @$roll_search; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo @$email_search; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo @$class_search; ?></td>     
        </tr>   
       <?php }  ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can see nothing happen:

[image]

Comment: did you check what's result coming in $result_search variable?

Comment: yes when i don't use function and write code on the same page its work

Comment: You are trying to access function variable out site of function, you have to use below code within loop that is incorrect, return records or define global variable in order to access out site function variables.
Hope it will be clear now

Comment: should you please explain its my first project Ravi Shankar

Comment: sure, give me 5 min I am sending you correct code

Comment: Thanks i'm try to fix it by my self project is complete and working but when i start clean up things i got stuck

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to connect to the mysql before the execution of the query. Maybe, you have put the connect code in the other file, however couldn't see it here so just wondering.

Comment: Shine Jacob yes i did

Comment: Okay, here are some of the things you can try (probably, you've already tried them):
1) Put an echo "inside while loop"; in the while loop to see it's been reached at all or not.
2) Since you've put @ before the $fname_search, $f_search, etc., which would not tell you why they're not been accessed. Try to remove them just to see what the error is. Probably, your code doesn't know where to find these variables since they're not defined (assigned) locally.
3) Since the variables are not an array themselves, it would only show the last record anyway.

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like below, hope it will work to you.

```
function search(){
        global $connection;
        $record_search = $_GET['search'];
        $record_search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $record_search);
          $result_search = mysqli_query($connection, $query_search);
        if(!$result_search){
            die("FAIL" . mysqli_error($connection));
        }
       $query_search = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_name='$record_search' OR       u_roll='$record_search' ";
       return $row_search = mysqli_fetch_array($result_search);
    }

<table class="table">
  <thead>
   <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Father Name</th>
            <th>School</th>
            <th>Roll No</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Class</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

<?php
$search_results = search();
$i=1;
foreach($search_results as $row_search){
    $name_search     =      $row_search[1];
    $f_search        =      $row_search[2];   
    $school_search   =      $row_search[3];
    $roll_search     =      $row_search[4];
    $email_search    =      $row_search[5];
    $class_search    =      $row_search[6];
    ?>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $i ?></th>
        <td><?php echo $name_search; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $f_search; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $school_search; ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $roll_search; ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $email_search; ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $class_search; ?></td>     
    </tr>   

    <?php 
    $i++;
    } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```